# Weird outcome: A lot of spaces instead of a proper sentence Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'm getting weird outputs with this script to monitor Shadow copies with nagios

If i run this script:

```
$runs = Get-ScheduledTaskInfo -TaskName "ShadowCopyVolume{eff29848-ac44-11e8-80b1-806e6f6e6963}" | Format-Wide -Property NumberOfMissedRuns

if ($runs -cmatch "0")
{
Write-host ok
exit 0
}
else
{
Write-Output "missed" $runs "runs"
exit 1
}
```

The outcome to it is:

```
PS C:\Program Files\NSClient++\scripts> C:\Program Files\NSClient++\scripts\check_scopy.ps1
missed


0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                


runs
```

Thats a lot of space being wasted.

So any suggestions to make it a proper sentence and not a galaxy of a ps outcome??

Comment: Try to put all three words together. Like so: `Write-Output $('missed {0} runs' -f $runs)`

Comment: `Write-Output "missed $($runs.length) runs"`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Format-*` to select a single property. Either use:

```
$runs = Get-ScheduledTaskInfo -TaskName "ShadowCopyVolume{eff29848-ac44-11e8-80b1-806e6f6e6963}" | 
    Select-Object -Expandproperty NumberOfMissedRunS
```

Or shorter:

```
$runs = (Get-ScheduledTaskInfo -TaskName "ShadowCopyVolume{eff29848-ac44-11e8-80b1-806e6f6e6963}").NumberOfMissedRuns
```

The property `NumberOfMissedRuns` is of type uint32, so a simple:

```
if ($runs){"missed {0} runs" -f $runs} else {write-Host "ok"}
```

should return the desired result.

BTW the usage of `-cmatch` in combination with a number doesn't make any sense - numbers don't have a case.